# Android is there a way to check for a specific device?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am writing an app that the layout is a little off on the Droid X2. Is there a way to detect in code if the device is a Droid X2? I would like to add a small amount amount of padding to the layout if it is.

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't you rather figure out what exactly is causing things to be off and then detect that instead of detecting the specific device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Build.PRODUCT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#PRODUCT).

Sample code:

```
if (Build.PRODUCT.contains("droid x2")) {
    // Add stuff.
}
```

Another important point to add. If this doesn't work, make sure to debug what the `Build.PRODUCT` contains in order to see if that is the correct info. Otherwise, you can check what [`Build.MODEL`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#MODEL) returns and go with that.

Comment: I don't think that is a reliable way to tell. Some users uses custom ROMs that may have different values.

Comment: Correct. Users with custom ROM:s can customize stuff, so I will, in this case, just think of users with standard values.

Answer (score 2):

Would this help? You could have a variable change based on the screen size instead of manually changing for devices:

```
getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
```

Comment: Well it isn't a screen size issue. All the HDPI devices look perfect except for the Droid X2.

Comment: Okay. Well I guess this would help: `android.os.Build.DEVICE;` returns a string.